# Wordpress all js path getting concatenated with .pagespeed.jm in my nginx server

Tags: wordpress

All of my wordpress js are getting concatenated with .pagespeed.jm for e.g.

```
wp-content/plugins/thrive-visual-
editor/editor/js/dist/editor.min.js,qver=2.1.8.pagespeed.jm.gbHmUDMili.js
```

and if I try to update js file then it's not reflecting on my front-end, it seems like it's caching and not updating my js.

My website is on Ubuntu and using nginx server, I tried to remove cache but still didn't worked, it worked only 1 time that my js file changes got reflected, but next time, it's the same and not updating at all now.

Anyone know what might be issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by installing pagespeed module wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/kagg-pagespeed-module/ and then purging the cache has removed all the cache from website,  and now everything is working fine. This plugin is helpful if pagespeed is enabled on apache or nginx server and someone wants to remove the cache from wordpress website, without messing server settings  (if someone don't know how to remove from server)